# CSV to postgresql using stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to do copy csv to database using stored procedure. My function is follows;

```
CREATE FUNCTION gis_portal.copycsv(IN path text) RETURNS void AS
'COPY gis_portal.temp_excel FROM path WITH DELIMITER'
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE LEAKPROOF;
```

query is

```
COPY gis_portal.temp_excel FROM path WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

with parameter path.

It is giving error as syntax error near path while creating function.

Please help me.

Comment: Always show the *full, exact text* of the error please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'COPY gis_portal.temp_excel FROM path WITH DELIMITER'
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

What delimiter? You must specify one if you use that keyword.

Try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gis_portal.copycsv(IN path text) RETURNS void AS $$
COPY gis_portal.temp_excel FROM path WITH DELIMITER ','
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

or whatever delimiter you want.

Additionally, in SQL functions you can't use the identifier you must use a positional parameter, like $1. But because `COPY` isn't a plannable statement you cannot use parameters in it. You will have to use PL/PgSQL and `EXECUTE` to run it as dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gis_portal.copycsv(IN path text) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('COPY gis_portal.temp_excel FROM %L WITH DELIMITER '',''', path);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the doubled quotes around the delimiter because it's now an SQL string.

Comment: Got an error  ERROR: syntax error at or near "path"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 101

Comment: @Santhucool ah, yes. In SQL functions you can't use the identifier you must use a positional parameter, like $1.